# Bitcoin Core does not connect to the network

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

i have installed Bitcoin Core 0.15.1 on my computer. I also made a Port Forwarding for Port 8333 and gave my Computer a static IP Adress.
My computer stats are: 
Intel Core i5 3.30GHz
AMD Radeon R9 380 Series
232 GB Samsung SSD 750 EVO 250GB
1863 GB Seagate HDD
16 GB RAM

But i have the problem, that de Core do not connect with the Network. (Left on the Bottom always stands "connecting to peers". But nothing happens. I waited 5 hours and there still stands "connecting to peers". But the Peer Tab(you can see in the picture) there are some peers connected i think. In the Debug File there are two Fails:

ProcessMessages(ping, 8 bytes) FAILED
ProcessMessages(getaddr, 0 bytes) FAILED

What can i do? Can someone help me?

[image: Bitcoin Core Peer Tab]

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I will have a good read of your question and see if I can identify an answer.

Comment: Are you using Bitcoin Core with all default configuration or some custom options? If you could edit your question to explain it would be helpful.

Comment: @Willtech thanks for the fast answer. I am running it with deufault configuration.

Comment: If you click on a peer in the Peers window you have posted a screenshot of, do any of the peers say that they are Outbound or, do all of them say that they are Inbound?